# Celery worker (on remote ec2) cannot communicate with rabbitmq(on another ec2)

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, rabbitmq, celery

I wrote an asynchronous email service that uses Celery and RabbitMQ for our Flask application. So I have rabbitmq running on one server - I created a user, vhost and set the permissions. I created an inbound TCP rule for port 5672. It's outbound rules are open to all. I have the celery application on another ec2 instance. The security for this one is pretty similar as well. Before I set up celeryd/supervisord - I tried to start the celery worker. BUt unfortunately it is giving me errors.

This is the celery config:

```
celery = Celery('myapp.celery', 
            broker = 'amqp://user:password@rabbit:5672/cel_host',
            backend = 'amqp:/cel_host',
            include = 'myapp.tasks')
```

This is the relevant traceback:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/backends/__init__.py", line 56, in get_backend_by_url
return get_backend_cls(backend, loader), url
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/utils/functional.py", line 133, in _M
value = fun(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/backends/__init__.py", line 45, in get_backend_cls
return symbol_by_name(backend, aliases)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/utils/__init__.py", line 84, in symbol_by_name
return getattr(module, cls_name) if cls_name else module
AttributeError
:
'module' object has no attribute '/cel_host'
```

*cel_host is vhost for RabbitMQ.

Everything was working fine when I was working on my local machine. Any help will be highly appreciated.

**Both instances are on a private subnet in our VPC

**EDIT:**
When I changed the broker_url to amqp://guest:guest@rabbit:5672//?ssl=1 - I get the error

```
consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest@rabbit:5672//: [Errno -2] Name or service not known.
```

So it's definitely connection issue that I am not sure how to fix

Comment: I seems you are missing one `/`. Url should be `amqp://cel_host`

Comment: The second '/' is the default virtual host for rabbitmq. So if I am using a different vhost I don't need the second '/'

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out what the problem was - and it was a dumb mistake on my part. The broker_url settings were fine but the backend setting wasn't.

The first part of the url - amqp:// is for the transport which is fixed. It is the trailing '/' which can be replaced by another vhost.

```
broker = 'amqp://<my_app:password>@<hostname>:5672/<vhost>',
            backend = 'amqp://<vhost>'
```

So in a sense Lycha you were correct!